# Nuxt - Purpose of README.md in each folder in the default project structure

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

I wonder why there is a README.md in every folder in the default project structure. Is it intended to keep it?

Answer (score 1):

Answer from the Nuxt Discord: Create-nuxt-app only recently made git optional, but it was automatically added previously. AFAIK git can't track empty directories, thus they used README.md to mitigate this. Other solutions I've seen are creating files like .gitignore or .gitkeep  inside a empty directory to ensure the empty directory is tracked/commited. It can be any name, but gitkeep seems to be what people gravitated to, yet I never did this personally.